# Ip hashing in Sitecore

Tags: configuration

Following the Sitecore documentation, if `Sitecore.Analytics.Lookups.IpHashProvider` is set then the IP addresses will be in hashed. My configuration file contains value as below:

```xml
<add name="default" salt="f54RYb4RT4ylVC" type="Sitecore.Analytics.Lookups.IpHashProvider, Sitecore.Analytics" />
```

But if I query my database using the following query:

```sql
SELECT InteractionId, LastModified, IpAddress, Country, City, Latitude, Longitude
  FROM [Prod_Xdb.Collection.Shard0].[xdb_collection].[InteractionFacets]

  CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (FacetData)
    with (
      IpAddress nvarchar(max) N'$.IpAddress', 
      Country nvarchar(max) N'$.Country', 
      City nvarchar(max) N'$.City', 
      Latitude nvarchar(max) N'$.Latitude', 
      Longitude nvarchar(max) N'$.Longitude'                     
    )

  WHERE FacetKey = 'IpInfo'
```

Then I can see the ip addresses stored in clear text, data such as *10.11.120.8* which is not hashed.

Is there a different configuration that needs to be set?

Comment: are you getting all the data like this or some data like this?

Comment: External PII Ip will be hashed. This looks like internal communication inside your solution.

Comment: Yes all the IP are shown in clear text.

Answer (score 2):

I have asked Sitecore the same question and their answer as below:

> In the InteractionFacets table of collection database, the real IPs are stored when Analytics.RedactIpAddress setting is set to false and the 0.0.0.0. IPs are stored when the setting is set to true.
>   The hashed IPs are stored in the ReferenceData database. In the ReferenceData database, they are always hashed. 
>   Unfortunately, the article that you refer is not mentioned that. I've made a request to correct it. Thank you for reporting that.
>   Actually, In Sitecore 8 there was the same logic but  - https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/82/setting_up_and_maintaining/xdb/contacts/ip_address_hashing*